# Rails validation best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, model

I have this validation for my `user`:

```
  validates :password,
  presence: true,
  confirmation: true,
  length: { minimum: 6 },
  :on => :create
```

This is obvious. When I'm creating (registering) a new `user`, I want to fill up their password hence that's why `presence: true`.

Case 1) When the user wants to update his account (lets say change his username), the form has only the `email` and `username` fields. That's ok and the validation is ok.

Case 2) He forgot his password and I send him his "forgotten password link" and he is on the page where he is creating his new password. The form has these two fields: password and password confirmation. However, **he leaves both of these fields empty** and submits the form. The validation passes **because it's only `:on => create`! because of case 1)**

I can not add `:on => update` because the **case 1)** wouldn't pass, because there is no password field.

What should I do in this situation? What is the best practice or what is the real word solution to this "problem"?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "case 2) woulnd't pass, because there is no password field"?

Comment: maxim pntyushenko: sorry I got typo it was "case 1) wouldn't pass"

Comment: Are you using ***Devise***?

Comment: Pavan: No that doesn't help. When I'm trying to edit/update the users information only (email, username) are there... the validation doesn't pass it throws ("password can't be blank")

Comment: Not 100% sure of this, but I think you could create TWO validation sets. One for `on: :create`, one for `on: :update`. The update one wouldn't include the presence or confirmation, only length.

Comment: One way is you can add `required => "required"` to the `text_fields` in the `form`(case 2) so that, the form cannot submit with a blank password

Comment: Add validation to your controller for change_password method, something like before_filter.

Comment: What is the action name which is used for forgotten_password page?

Comment: the action is called "update"

Comment: Are you sure? I guess it could be a different action. Please check

Comment: So the action which displays "forgotten_password" page is "edit", however  when I hit the "change password" button on that page it fires "update" action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done for this situation is instead of using `on: :create`, I use a virtual attribute that I set only when setting/changing the password. Something like this:

```
validates :password, if: :changing_password?
attr_accessor :password_scenario

def changing_password?
  self.password_scenario.present?
end
```

Then in your controller, you would simply set password_scenario to true whenever you are requiring password to be present.

Comment: I wrote a gem that uses this approach with a pretty bow and wrapping paper: https://github.com/pdobb/conditional_validation

Comment: @pdobb +1 I wasn't aware of your gem. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thank you very much that's what I was looking for :) btw.. is it like hacking it or is it legitimate approach what I could use in real life project?